# Problem with sympy-expressions while solving intersection of two functions

Tags: python, sympy

I'm new to sympy and I'm just trying to calculate the intersection of two functions.
I've got the warning "Add/Mul with non-Expr args has been deprecated since SymPy 1.7. Use Expr args instead."
Also I've don't get any output.

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x')
f, g = sym.Function('f')(x), sym.Function('g')(x)

f, g = x - 1, -2*x + 5
x_value = sym.solveset(f-g, x)
y_value = f.subs(x, x_value)

output = "S(" + sym.latex(x_value) + "|" + sym.latex(y_value) + ")"
print(output)
```

In the sympy-documentation I neither find "non-expressions" nor "expression arguments".
Also I'm a little bit confused that the FiniteSets are non subscriptable. So when I'm trying to use x_value[0], I'll get an TypeError. Ok, FiniteSets ar not ordered and it would work if I use "for i in x_value: print(i)", but that solution seems very odd to me. Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance for your help,
lycaine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't add fake "tags" to question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "You should not \*force\* a tag into your title. Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for… The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."

Comment: You can use something like ` list(x_value)[0]`

Comment: Hi Oscar,
Thx for the tip. That should make the output handling much more easy.
But I still get the "Add/Mul with non-Expr args has been deprecated since SymPy 1.7. Use Expr args instead." warning. Do you know how to handle this?